# Mac 600% CPU usage by java & heavy I/O use from deleted app

Tags: mac, cpu, performance, process, fan

After downloading "MCreator" to start into coding again, I ran into heavy problems. A process called "java" is using 600% CPU constantly, fans are running at max. Please see the screenshots below:

**Thank you for your help in advance!.**

Screenshots of the process:

[image: screenshot1]
[image: screenshot2]
[image: screenshot3]

Comment: Have you tried terminating the process?

Comment: yes, didn't do anything. I didn't force quit though; should I attempt that?

Comment: by the way: the program which causes the high CPU is deleted. files from the trash are still controlling the java process though, somehow

Comment: Yeah, try force quiting.

Comment: "Deleted app" => NOT UNINSTALLED. Is it possible to move it back from "deleted files (restore files)? If yes: Then "Do the right thing" -> uninstall.